# Counting unique combination frequencies in a market-basket

Tags: python, frequency, sklearn-pandas

I have a set of 1000000 market-baskets containing 1-4 items each. I would like to calculate the frequency of each unique combination of items purchased.

The data is organized as such:

```
[in] print(training_df.head(n=5))

[out]                     product_id
transaction_id                      
0000001                   [P06, P09]
0000002         [P01, P05, P06, P09]
0000003                   [P01, P06]
0000004                   [P01, P09]
0000005                   [P06, P09]
```

In this example [P06, P09] has a frequency of two and all other combinations have a frequency of one. I have created the following binary matrix and calculated the frequency of each individual item as such:

```
# Create a matrix for the transactions
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

product_ids = ['P{:02d}'.format(i+1) for i in range(10)]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes = product_ids)
training_df1 = training_df.drop('product_id', 1).join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(training_df['product_id']),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=training_df.index))

# Calculate the support count for each product (frequency)
train_product_support = {}
for column in training_df1.columns:
    train_product_support[column] = sum(training_df1[column]>0)
```

How can I calculate the frequency of each unique combination of 1-4 items that are present in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you cant use `df.groupby('product_id').count()`, this is the best I could come up with. We make a dict with the string representation of lists as keys, and count occurrences in it.

```
counts = dict()
for i in df['product_id']:
    key = i.__repr__()
    if key in counts:
        counts[key] += 1
    else:
        counts[key] = 1
```

Comment: this is how I would solve this as well, but I would guess that order does not matter. therefore I would throw in `key = sorted(key)` to make any arrangement of the same items equivalent

Comment: `defaultdict` is probably nicer to work with https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Might also want a `frozenset` instead of a `str` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset

Comment: I'll read up on `frozenset` and `defaultdict`, thanks. OP, if order doesn't matter, make sure to sort as pointed out by @JasonStein

Comment: @JasonStein i tried your suggestion but get "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" I wanted to add it just to be sure, but I think that each row is already ordered (ie- "P01,P09" and NO "P09,P01"

Comment: Can I sort the dictionary by # of items in basket, and then by frequency of combinations?

Comment: @zsad512 can you provide an example of what you mean? I don't follow that. You want the order you see things in the dictionary to be sorted, or you want to sort frequencies before counting the occurrences?

Comment: I would like the dictionary to be sorted by number of items in the key, and then have the keys to be sorted by frequency

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
df['frozensets'] = df.apply(lambda row: frozenset(row.product_id),axis=1)
df['frozensets'].value_counts()
```

Creates a column of frozensets (hashable, and ignoring ordering) from product_ids, and then counts the number of each unique value.

Comment: This sorts the data from greatest frequency to least frequency (of unique combinations). How can I further sort the unique combinations according to the number of items in the combination?